# Simulating Clifford operations on stabilizer states with tableau representation

Tags: stabilizer-code, clifford-group

I have several questions regarding on how to simulate stabilizer states with tableau representation.

First, I have observed that tableau representation of composite Clifford operators $UV$ where $U, V \in \mathcal{C}_n$,can be calculated by $T_U T_V$, matrix multiplication of two tableau, where $T_U$ and $T_V$ are the tableau representations of $U$ and $V$ respectively. The tableau representation I am using is the format as same as [Improved Simulation of Stabilizer Circuits](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0406196) by Scott Aaronson and Daniel Gottesman

The question is: why does this method work-how do I prove this method is valid? Also, how do I compute phase row of the tableau in that method? I tried several method to figure out how to do it but every attempts failed...

Comment: Please add one of your try. Maybe it will be helpful to reveal where your problem is hidden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my long and crude attempt to my question:
Long story short, I have given up simulating Clifford operation on stabilizer with matrix multiplication method. Instead, I have implemented the following method for Clifford groups acting on two qubits.

Since generator is evolved by Clifford operation, $U \in \mathcal{C}$ by $U g U^\dagger = g'$. In tableau representation, it shows mapping of generators, $XI, IX, ZI, $ and $IZ$ onto $U(XI)U^\dagger = R_1, U(IX)U^\dagger = R_2, U(ZI)U^\dagger = R_3, $ and $U(IZ)U^\dagger = R_4$ where $R_i$ represents row of the tableau representing the resulting Pauli group. Therefore, if I want to see the effect of the Clifford operator on my tableau that represents $XX$, for example, I can find the resulting generator by $R_1 R_2 = U(XI)U^\dagger U(IX)U^\dagger = U(XX)U^\dagger$ where $R_1 R_2$ is just a multiplication of pair of Pauli matrices.  Signs can be kept track during the calculation so that solves my problem with signs.

Therefore, if I have two operators, represented by $T_V$ and $T_U$ which represent the resulting generators when they act on $XI, IX, ZI,$ and $IZ,$ effect of $U$ on $V|0\rangle^{\otimes n}$ can be easily found by applying the method above. Read off the row of $T_V$, match the Pauli string by multiplying rows of the $U$, once the input Pauli string is matched with ones with rows of $T_V$, replace it with new ones $R_1 R_2$ like an example given above.

So unless there are better and more efficient method (honestly, there will be but I have not searched hard enough), I will go with this method to simulate a Clifford operator on my stabilizer circuit.